# How do I make the whitespace behaviour in a <textarea> and a HTML preview match?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, richtextbox

I have a `<textarea>` element. When the user fills it, you can see the spaces they made and when they pressed Enter to jump to the next line.

This is great, but when I see the HTML output, the result differs. It is an endless sentence without line breaks.

Using only HTML or JavaScript, how can I fix this?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Please post some code if you want to get a response

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share your code or what you have tried to get good answers!!!

Comment: I don't think it's vague. The OP wants the line break behaviour in the textarea to match that of the HTML output. He doesn't want to use a full-blown WYSIWYG editor to fix the problem, and he's right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
<p style="white-space: pre-wrap"></p>
<p style="white-space: pre"></p>
<pre></pre>

pre-wrap:
Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks 
pre:
Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line breaks Acts like the <pre> tag in HTML
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just taking what is entered in a textarea and outputing it as html, you would see this.  For starters, you could replace all spaces with `&nbsp;` and all newlines with `<br>`.  Or put the output in `<pre>` tags.  (In either case, you will also want to replace some other characters with entities too.)

Comment: Don't forget CSS: `white-space: pre`